# Typescript generic : Property 'pass' does not exist on type 'T'.ts(2339)

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
// callback functions
const fetchData = (userId:number, cb:any) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const fakeData = {
            name: "bob",
            id: userId,
            pass: 1234
        };
        cb(fakeData);
    }, 500)
}

interface Idata {
    name: string,
    id: number
}

const afterFetchData = <T extends Idata>(data: T) => {
    console.log("your data is", data.pass)
}
```

How can I put any type of value inside the `fakeData` and accept it without using `any` in `afterFetchData` function ?

now I have this error : Property 'pass' does not exist on type 'T'.ts(2339)

Comment: `T extends Idata`, so it's only required to have name and id.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you please give me an example of the correct way ?

Comment: Your `Idata` interface does not include `pass` property.

Comment: Not really, because without more context it's not clear what the correct way might be. Maybe you should add pass to the interface. Maybe afterFetchData should accept any. Maybe it should check whether pass is defined before trying to log it.

Comment: So you need to tell us why you are trying to access `pass` property that doesn't exist

Comment: this is just a playground to understand the correct way. so I just imagined the fakeData can be filled from server and I might not know all the fields to put inside the interface

Comment: so I wanted to know what's the best way to accept any kind of values

Answer (score 2):

If you know that there will be always some properties in there like `id` and `name`, but you are not sure about `pass`, you can do this :

```
console.log("your data is", data['pass'])
```

Otherwise you should leave the fakeData untyped or use `any` type

Comment: Thanks @MajiD, but still I got the same error
```Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"pass"' can't be used to index type 'Idata'.
  Property 'pass' does not exist on type 'Idata'.ts(7053)```

Comment: if you dont know anything about the server response then i think you should use `any`